# jQuery: Circulate plugin: stopping midway in animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Has anyone had any luck in altering the plug-in code so that one might animate an object in "3d" space for only a 1/4 or 1/2 turn?

As it stands, an object must complete a full circle before stopping or looping.

And for those who haven't seen it yet: http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the plugin starts on line 46 in the code:

```
base.$el.animate( ... )
 .animate( ... )
 .animate( ... )
 .animate( ... )
```

Each `animate` function takes care of 1/4 rotation. So if you just want to hack it, remove the last two animate calls for a `1/2` rotation, and remove three if you just want the first `1/4`. Either way, you want to play with those four `animate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 4 objects, position them on top of each other then use z-index to hide each object for 3/4 of it's revolution.

```
$(obj1).circulate({ ... , zIndexValue: [ 1, -1, -1, -1] });
$(obj2).circulate({ ... , zIndexValue: [-1,  1, -1, -1] });
$(obj3).circulate({ ... , zIndexValue: [-1, -1,  1, -1] });
$(obj4).circulate({ ... , zIndexValue: [-1, -1, -1,  1] });
```

This works but I'd really like to have a different image for each 1/8 of a revolution so if you or anyone else comes up with a better solution let me know.